# Update specific value in xml file by bash

Tags: linux, xml, bash

I need update specific value in xml in automatic way by bash script.
My xml file has a lot of similar line like:

```
<xml>
   <main>
      <buildElement name="test_one" version="" path="" />
      <buildElement name="test_two" version="" path="" />
   </main>
</xml>
```

I need find element name  "test_one" and edit version.
I am trying this, but it's not help:

Expected output:

```
<xml>
   <main>
      <buildElement name="test_one" version="some_value" path="" />
      <buildElement name="test_two" version="" path="" />
   </main>
</xml>
```

I am trying get this by xmlstarlet and sed, but is not working f.e:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//xml/main/buildElement/name="test_one"/version' --value 'some_value' myXML.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath syntax is incorrect. You need to use `@` to refer to attributes, and to search for a particular element you need a filter expression. You want:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update \
  '//xml/main/buildElement[@name="test_one"]/@version' \
  -v some_value myXML.xml
```

Which will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <main>
    <buildElement name="test_one" version="some_value" path=""/>
    <buildElement name="test_two" version="" path=""/>
  </main>
</xml>
```

Comment: thanks, I use this but... I see changes in console print, but no in the file. Why it's not store in a file?

Comment: ok, I solved my problem by change options - xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u

Answer (score 0):

```
'//xml/main/buildElement/name="test_one"/version'
```

You want

```
'//xml/main/buildElement[@name="test_one"]/@version'
```

(Basically, you seem to be guessing, and that's not going to get you very far with XPath. Do some reading.)